# Can I ask a question like "How can I colorize these sprites"?

Tags: discussion

I finished to make a 2D game for smartphones, I'm not an artist, so I payed one guy to make me the main character, but I did the rest alone. I'm not happy with the colors of buildings and background, I want to ask help/suggestion from someone with better "eye" than me.

Can I ask this question? (posting images)

Comment: I would say yes, it is about colour theory and visual contrast. You must post some screenshots, point out as precisely as possible what you do not think works and what does. Start your question with "Critique:-----"